# Setting camera resolution in OpenCV - pre-built vs. custom build

Tags: python, opencv

Using OpenCV we are able to get the camera resolution from a USB webcam if supported by

```
import cv2

vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vs.get(3)
>> 640
```

and setting a resolution if supported by

```
import cv2

vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
vs.set(3,800)
```

However, I am facing a problem with this. If I install OpenCV using the pre-built from apt-get as

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

I can set the properties of the camera and use it just fine. If I custom build my OpenCV installation, I can only get the properties of the camera but *not* set them. I can still use the camera in OpenCV, but not change anything.

If I set some properties beforehand using **v4l2-ctl**, the changes are registered but when OpenCV initializes the camera it will overwrite these settings.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this occurs? Am I missing some vital library in my custom OpenCV build that is included in pre-built binaries and somehow not standard?

**Edit (build information):**

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE    
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local      
      -D ENABLE_NEON=ON     
      -D ENABLE_VFPV3=ON     
      -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF    
      -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF     
      -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF 
      -D WITH_JPEG=ON 
      -D BUILD_JPEG=OFF 
      -D JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR=/opt/libjpeg-turbo/include/   
      -D JPEG_LIBRARY=/opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib32/libjpeg.a 
      -D WITH_V4L=ON ..
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- FP16 is not supported by C++ compiler
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing:  JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-base-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-base-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-video-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-video-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-app-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-app-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-riff-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10'
--   No package 'gstreamer-pbutils-0.10' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394-2'
--   No package 'libdc1394-2' found
-- Checking for module 'libdc1394'
--   No package 'libdc1394' found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- Checking for module 'libavresample'
--   No package 'libavresample' found
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing:  Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- A library with BLAS API found.
-- A library with LAPACK API found.
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing:  JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /mnt/ext2/opencv-4.0.0/build/python_loader
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/corner.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/filter.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/imgproc/src/resize.sse4_1.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: <BUILD>/modules/dnn/layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/features2d/src/fast.avx2.cpp
-- Excluding from source files list: modules/calib3d/src/undistort.avx2.cpp
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.0.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2019-04-14T12:06:42Z
--     Host:                        Linux 4.14.71-ti-r80 armv7l
--     CMake:                       3.7.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    VFPV3 NEON
--       requested:                 DETECT
--       required:                  VFPV3 NEON
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/local/bin/c++  (ver 6.3.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/local/bin/gcc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python3 python_bindings_generator stitching ts video videoio
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java js python2
--     Applications:                perf_tests apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     GTK+:                        YES (ver 3.22.11)
--       GThread :                  YES (ver 2.50.3)
--       GtkGlExt:                  NO
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib32/libjpeg.a (ver 62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.8)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (built-in)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /mnt/ext2/opencv-4.0.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.3)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.3)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

**Update 25.04.2019**

Per suggestion I made sure to install gstreamer as well - see below for OpenCV build information:

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.4.0 =====================================
  Version control:               unknown

  Platform:
    Timestamp:                   2019-04-25T06:51:57Z
    Host:                        Linux 4.14.98-v7+ armv7l
    CMake:                       3.7.2
    CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
    CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
    Configuration:               RELEASE

  CPU/HW features:
    Baseline:                    VFPV3 NEON
      requested:                 DETECT
      required:                  VFPV3 NEON

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
    C++11:                       YES
    C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 6.3.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfpu=neon -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfpu=neon -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
    C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfpu=neon -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
    C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -mfpu=neon -mfp16-format=ieee -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
    Linker flags (Release):
    Linker flags (Debug):
    ccache:                      NO
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt
    3rdparty dependencies:

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann highgui imgcodecs imgproc ml objdetect photo python2 python_bindings_generator shape stitching superres ts video videoio videostab
    Disabled:                    js world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev java python3 viz
    Applications:                perf_tests apps
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI:
    GTK+:                        YES (ver 2.24.31)
      GThread :                  YES (ver 2.50.3)
      GtkGlExt:                  NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib32/libjpeg.a (ver )
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpng.so (ver 1.6.28)
    TIFF:                        /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libtiff.so (ver 42 / 4.0.8)
    JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:
      base:                      YES (ver 1.10.4)
      video:                     YES (ver 1.10.4)
      app:                       YES (ver 1.10.4)
      riff:                      YES (ver 1.10.4)
      pbutils:                   YES (ver 1.10.4)
    libv4l/libv4l2:              NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h
    gPhoto2:                     NO

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (built-in)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  YES (carotene (ver 0.0.1))

  NVIDIA CUDA:                   NO

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /home/pi/opencv-3.4.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.13)
    Libraries:                   /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.13)
    numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.12.1)
    packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages

  Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7

  Java:
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        NO

  Install to:                    /usr/local
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using `v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext` list the following:

```
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Index       : 0
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'MJPG' (compressed)
        Name        : Motion-JPEG
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x600
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 352x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1920x1080
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)

        Index       : 1
        Type        : Video Capture
        Pixel Format: 'YUYV'
        Name        : YUYV 4:2:2
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x600
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 352x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
```

and then trying to set something in OpenCV:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.get(3)
>> 640.0

cap.set(3,1920)
>> True

cap.get(3)
>> 640.0
```

Any suggestions to what is going on?

Comment: Can you share your build information?

Comment: Absolutely - build information is now included. V4L is on.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev` and make clean?

Comment: I don't see any issue, maybe DC1394 is missing but according to doc it doesn't affect the width, height properties. As an alternative, I'd try setting the camera parameters using gstreamer backend.

Comment: @Christoffer I will try that!

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf not very experienced with using gstreamer - can you point to any examples or information on how to do that?

Comment: @Jesper As the build information, `GStreamer: NO`, the GStreamer is not installed in your machine, to try to install the GStreamer, and then cmake will automatically detect the GStreamer (on Ubuntu, but on Windows you need to add GStreamer to the system path, and cmake path).

Comment: @BahramdunAdil thanks for that. I will try this. I am compiling for arm (RPi3/BeagleBone Black), but that should be the same as for Ubuntu, right? ```sudo apt-get install libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev``` and then cmake will automatically detect it?

Comment: @Jesper Yes, Ubuntu will automatically detect it, you need to run like this to install GStreamer: `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0` and  `sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-dev` It will install everything.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Thanks. Will give it a go.

Comment: @Jesper, Once you have built opencv with gstreamer, create a gstreamer pipeline for webcam using `gst_str = ("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080  ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! appsink")`. Afterwards, pass this to video capture function as `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`. You won't need to perform `cap.set()`

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I tried your suggestion. Something odd is going on - see updated question.

Comment: @Christoffer  I tried your suggestion. Something odd is going on - see updated question.

Comment: @Jesper Try setting both width and height. So `cap.set(3,1920)` and `cap.set(4,1080)`

Comment: @Christoffer it seemed it was stuck in YUYV and could not switch to MJPEG for the high res. When I did ```fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')``` and ```cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)``` it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that the final issue had to do with OpenCV not using the MJPEG format rather than defaulting to YUYV. Changing this using:

```
import cv2

vs = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
vs.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, fourcc)
```

fixed the problem and I can now set the camera using the `vs.set()` commands.

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but was unable. When I manually do `v4l2-ctl --set-formats` and pass 1920x1080, it shows this change via `v4l2-ctl --all` afterward, but cv2 still opens it with 640x480 YUVV, and despite running the above, I get the same behavior with `cam.set(3, 1920)`, with `cam.get(3)` showing `640.0` immediately after.